# Rails reuse existing controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

There is a `PartsController` in my webapp and it works wonderfully well. It sends the right data to view so the view can render charts/stats/data etc. it and everything is full working order.

Now I've got another functionality in my app where I can combine parts into a product. And now I've got a `ProductController` which I want basically to retain exact the same behavior as parts controller, meaning I'd like to reuse views which exist from my parts controller but just send different data to view. `PartsController` would send one data and `ProductController` would send other data to the view but of course they would be of a same type.

What is the best way to do this? Maybe for productcontroller to inherit the parts controller? is this even possible in rails to override certain methods in controller but to use the same views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to share the controller logic between `PartsController` and `ProductController`, just the views. If so, put the templates in a common directory, and in the controllers, do this to render:

```
 # imagine the templates are in app/views/products
 render 'products/action_name'
```

If you additionally want to share controller logic, there are a couple options:

1. Both inherit from a common superclass
2. One inherits from the other (and overrides selected methods)
3. Both `include` a common `Module`